# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've recently wanted to make a PHP file, but then i got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /storage/ssd4/088/5637088/public_html/includes/global.php:109 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd4/088/5637088/public_html/index.php(8): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/088/5637088/public_html/includes/global.php on line 109
```

I've tried the MySQLi but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Heres my code

```
https://pastebin.com/irz2ni3W
```

Comment: Please, __paste__ your code here as text, don't provide links to other resources.

Comment: Your code still contains a lot of mysql_ calls.

Comment: PHP 7 is here to say you can't use `mysql_query` any more. Time to update your code.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community! A couple of notes: describing the observed behavior as "not working" doesn't provide any useful information, in terms of asking someone to help determine the root cause of the problem. There is no code provided in the question/ Providing a link to another site is akin to not providing no code at all (content gets removed, links get broken.).

Comment: Hello. My code is too long with 2k characters.